# Vim conceal indentation. Replace indentation spaces with utf-8 chars

Tags: regex, vim, indentation

I use four spaces for indent. I would like to replace the indentation with some utf-8 chars.

What I have:

1.

```
def foo(bar):
    for jaffa in bar:
        print jaffa
```

2.

```
var foo = function(bar){
    bar.forEach(function(jaffa){
        console.log(jaffa);
    });
}
```

What I want:

1.

```
def foo(bar):
►for jaffa in bar:
►►print jaffa
```

2.

```
var foo = function(bar){
►bar.forEach(function(jaffa){
►►console.log(jaffa);
►});
}
```

I tried using the conceal myself. But couldn't come up with the pattern to match the indentation spaces.

**Q: How would I accomplish changing the indentation to utf-8 chars using vim conceal as described in the examples?**

Comment: Didn't you try regex substitute like :%s/^\s/>/g ?

Comment: `set noexpandtab`, `set conceallevel=2` then `syntax match TAB /^I/ conceal cchar=►`; Enter `^I` by pressing `<C-v>Tab` and you'll good to go!